# How can I determine the password for my Cisco EA3500 router?

Tags: router, passwords

Ok, I'm about to tear my hair out.  While I was in the hospital last year, my router in my dental office died, and I had to have a local IT guy come out and replace it. I gave him the password and had him duplicate all the existing settings for the new Cisco EA3500 router.

Fast forward a year later, I just discovered the roach motel next door has piggybacked a Netgear expander on to my public WiFi network!  So now I'm trying to login to my router and block that stupid expander, but my password doesn't work!!!  The only thing I can think of is that the IT guy did not type in my old password exactly like the old one (it was a 14 character password that included upper and lower case letters).  They claim they used the exact same password, but clearly they did not.

So, I know I can reset the stupid thing, but I have spent HOURS and HOURS over the years tweaking my little office network so certain employees/MAC addresses can access (or not access) parts of my network or Internet.  In hindsight I should have specifically told the IT guy to save the config file after he got it all set up, then I could just reset the router and import the settings.

I obviously have physical access to the router.  Is there a way to determine the password without a brute force attack?  I have tried every combination of the old password I can think of with no luck. I am just sick at the idea of having to go back and set this thing up again from scratch.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are not going to be able to brute force a 14 character password which depending on the security your network is using is the only method you can use.

Comment: Are you positive you are using the correct user for the router?  That sometimes changes between models/makes.

Comment: "Are you positive you are using the correct user for the router? That sometimes changes between models/make"  I thought of that and you are exactly correct.  I have tried that as well.  The username I had was Admin, but I have no idea if they changed that, too.  I've tried a ton of variations on that, too. :P

Comment: The security of my network is irrelevant because the router is right at my desk.  I can attempt password combinations all day, as long as that router will not lock me out (and it hasn't yet). I guess if they used a simple password and didn't even use mine, a brute force attack could be worth the effort.

Comment: Just do a hard reset on the router and reconfigure it.

Comment: Seriously, kobaltz?  I know I can do that.  Unless you have been in my shoes, you don't know how frustrating it is to have spent a ton of time working on something and then have to go back and do it all again. I am looking for some clever way to get back in to my own router WITHOUT resetting it.  I even went through the Firefox and IE passwords on the PC thinking maybe he had stored it when he accessed it, but all I could find was my original password.

Comment: If it wasn't too expensive I would consider sending to some forensic lab or Cisco and pay them to extract the settings file for me. Anyone ever heard of that before?

Comment: @Frett Do they really do that or are you just wishing?

Comment: Have you considered asking the IT guy? Maybe he still has some notes about which password he set.

Comment: http://www.justanswer.com/computer-networking/6srem-installed-linksys-ea3500-router-few-months-ago.html  Maybe this will help.

Comment: I asked the company and they say he would not have changed the password to something else without informing me.  I think it was probably an honest mistake, but it was a year ago, so I think they literally have no idea. I was doing the whole thing from a chemo bed in another state, and going through relayed messages from one of my employees to the IT guy. I just wish I had had the presence of mind to make sure he saved the settings file.  And yes, I already searched the PC for one. :(

Comment: @chipperman573 Maybe I am just wishing, but I would think they could do that!

Comment: @Kevin-Panko Thanks and that would be helpful if I needed the wireless password, but I already have that.  What I need is the main administrator password to change the settings.

Comment: And thank you guys for the serious answers.  I know most people are shaking their heads going "Dude just reset it!!!".  I do know a little about tech stuff, but I thought I would ask the REALLY smart ones here.  Thank you for not blowing me off.

Comment: You almost got it.  It's case-sensitive, so not "Admin" but "admin".  And you said it yourself -- if you've spent all that money getting it set up the way you want it, SAVE THE CONFIGURATION to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Try truncating. First 13, first 12, first 11, first 10 characters of the 14 character password.

and, of course, try "admin" (groan)

Comment: hmmm... definintely worth trying. I'll report back.

Comment: Other "tricks" include trying with caps-lock on & with Num lock on.

Comment: LOL yes I tried admin and every other default that Cisco/Linksys uses. :)   Ok, the caps-lock thing is a great idea, too.  Which would explain how he could mistype the info twice...if that's what happened.  My fingers are tired from typing the same stuff over and over again.  I wish my router had a superior security device on it, like a fingerprint scanner! (Just tiring to maintain a sense of humor, so I don't put my head through the wall) :)

Comment: Ah – But then you would have had to cut off your finger and handed it to the guy when you were in the hospital - got to think these "superior" things through all the way. ;-) Meanwhile a timer (or just pulling the plug at the end of the day) outside of office hours might put a crimp in the roach motel.